# Calling function in where condition on query

Tags: mysql, function, user-defined-functions

I have one customized function created in `MySQL`.
I want to call it in where condition of query like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME

WHERE (FUNCTION_NAME);
```

Is this possible?

Note: My function returns values like a query

Comment: Tool: [http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

Comment: Using functions in the `WHERE` clause is poor practice as it has poor performance due to reduction of index use. Unless you are intending to `SELECT ... WHERE col = function()`?

Comment: Function looks like following "SELECT FUNCTION_NAME('columnname','a');"  will return "columnname LIKE ('%a%')"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use functions on queries...
the only thing is your condition, if you are going to use something like
`SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id = FUNCTION_NAME;` be sure that FUNTION_NAME return a number and not a query, or if you are going to use  `where in`, 
`SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id in (FUNCTION_NAME);` be sure that FUNCTION_NAME return the query with one column.  The important thing about the function_name is the thing that is returned, like a value, or a query, etc

Comment: Function looks like following "SELECT FUNCTION_NAME('columnname','a');" will return "columnname LIKE ('%a%')" so it return like query... But not working for me. It is working fine in prepared statement but in case of direct query.

Comment: try using `call function_name(('columnname','a');`

Comment: I tried with "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE call function_name(('columnname','a');" but it doesn't doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: no, try this: `set @a:=function_name();select * from table_name where @a` (condition)

Comment: Hmmm... I try this.. But query returns no result. Just to make this clear - I am not using stored procedure to implement it. I want to make this happen in query window that we use.

Comment: @user1044895 can you add your SP in your code? what your ST return you?

Comment: If I put that in stored procedure then it returns expected result, But I want it to work it without using code in SP. It should work in normal query window. It seems both our normal query (select * from table_name) query and calling function (call function_name) doesn't work together.